# How can we use Kafka topic itself as data storage?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

How can we use Kafka topic itself as data storage? I do not want to take care of separate database systems. I want to do all CRUD operations in Kafka itself. What kind of technology are used? How can we run queries? Do we have terminal or UI?

Comment: Kafka is not a database, but is a message-streaming and processing software. You cannot run queries on it as on a database. For accessing any specific data from the topic, you can only access it via the kafka message offset, and hence you cannot query as in a database.

Comment: Any kind of CRUD operations that you need to do would have to be done via an external system which processes the kafka message stream and possibly stores it for querying.

Comment: @MadhuBhat, how can we access data from Kafka message offset? Do we use KSQL or what are the ways? Can we have REST endpoint, this endpoint can have some command that can look message in Kafka offset then return the value?

Comment: There are different libraries and CLI tools to access a kafka message via the offset. Depends on your overall system design and tech stack you use. But I would highly advise against using kafka like a database, because it's not a replacement for a database.

Answer (score 2):

All records in a Kafka topic are immutable; there is no `UD` of CRUD. You publish (Create) and consume (Read), then if you have retention/compaction enabled, only then would records ever get "deleted".

With *Kafka Streams* you have the option of having a State Store, which is backed by RocksDB, as a KV-Store database, and can be used [alongside ksqlDB](http://ksqldb.io/) if you want "SQL-like" query semantics. Here, you can introduce "updates" by writing a new value for an existing key.

Beyond that, I'd suggest adding an external database for more persistent storage and querying features, for example Clickhouse, Druid or Apache Pinot.

However, some additional references

- [It's Okay to Store data in Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/okay-store-data-apache-kafka/)
- [New York Times use-case](https://www.confluent.io/blog/publishing-apache-kafka-new-york-times/)

---

> Do we have terminal

Sounds like you've not used Kafka? It [comes with terminal commands, yes](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart).

> or UI

Not built-in, no.

---

> What kind of technology are used?

Clients are written in many languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use delete policy COMPACT,
Delete - sending keys with null value  tombstone message
Upsert - Key with Value